# turtlebot with gyro but no kinect

Tags: ros, turtlebot, gyro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to test out my set up. I just installed the gyro according to http://answers.ros.org/question/717/is-an-imu-required-to-run-turtlebot-stack. I want to verify its working correctly but when I run the calibration command

> roslaunch turtlebot_calibration
> calibrate.launch

I am getting error " Still waiting for imu ".

Also, I am still waiting for my kinect, when I run

> `roslaunch turtlebot_bringup robot.launch`

I get "[/openni_camera] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected"
also when I run the minimial.launch file I am getting this error as well...

> respawning... IOError: [Errno 13]
> Permission denied:
> '/home/ros/.ros/log/a7cc963c-a446-11e0-a0ae-001d72a199a1/turtlebot_node-3.log'
> [turtlebot_node-3] process has died
> [pid 28495, exit code 1]. log files:
> /home/ros/.ros/log/a7cc963c-a446-11e0-a0ae-001d72a199a1/turtlebot_node-3*.log
> respawning...respawning...

**How can I test my gyro to make sure its working and get turtlebot working without kinect until I have it? Please include location of file to edit. **

Results of roswtf:

```
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
connection to [/app_manager] timed out
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 5 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /diagnostic_aggregator:
   * /diagnostics
 * /robot_pose_ekf:
   * /imu/data
   * /odom
 * /robot_state_publisher:
   * /joint_states
 * /openni_manager:
   * /cloud_throttled

WARNING The following nodes are unexpectedly connected:
 * /openni_manager->/kinect_laser (/openni_manager/bond)
 * /kinect_breaker_enabler->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /pointcloud_throttle->/kinect_laser (/openni_manager/bond)
 * /app_manager->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /openni_camera->/kinect_laser_narrow (/openni_manager/bond)
 * /pointcloud_throttle->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /kinect_laser->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /robot_pose_ekf->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /kinect_laser_narrow->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /robot_state_publisher->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /diagnostic_aggregator->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /pointcloud_throttle->/kinect_laser_narrow (/openni_manager/bond)
 * /openni_camera->/kinect_laser (/openni_manager/bond)
 * /openni_camera->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /openni_manager->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /openni_manager->/kinect_laser_narrow (/openni_manager/bond)

WARNING These nodes have respawned at least once:
 * turtlebot_node-3 (9)
 * kinect_laser-12 (2)
 * kinect_laser_narrow-13 (2)

WARNING These nodes have died:
 * app_manager-2
 * turtlebot_laptop_battery-4

WARNING No tf messages

Found 2 error(s).

ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:
 * /app_manager

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:
 * service [/turtlebot/start_app] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/turtlebot/start_app], address [rosrpc://ros-desktop:45707]
 * service [/turtlebot/list_apps] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/turtlebot/list_apps], address [rosrpc://ros-desktop:45707]
 * service [/turtlebot/stop_app] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/turtlebot/stop_app], address [rosrpc://ros-desktop:45707]
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10464/turtlebot-with-gyro-but-no-kinect/) by [xalu](https://answers.ros.org/users/754/xalu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2011-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-07-01**:
eventhough the roslaunch is waiting for the kinect all the other software is still running and you can run robot.launch. It will just print to the screen leeting you know it's not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

okay. To answer my own question. I needed to edit permission..specifically of my Log folder. So I changed it to chmod -r 777 ~/.ros/log and I was able to get the minimal.launch file going.

After that I was able to get the calibration error to change from

> waiting for IMU

to

> [INFO] [WallTime: 1309587548.929387] Still waiting for scan

.. Which in my book right now means its working :D
So I think my question is answered.

---

Originally posted by [xalu](https://answers.ros.org/users/754/xalu/) with karma: 68 on 2011-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

open up the turtlebot_dashboard click on the wrench icon to show the diagnostics. Then look at the gyro info under sensors, you will see whether the gyro status is OK. if you double click on the gyro item in the list you will see the the value of the calibration which is  ~500

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-07-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xalu](https://answers.ros.org/users/754/xalu/) on 2011-07-02**:
Thanks for tip. I am all green and my gyro is giving me updates so its working :)